# Cannot connect to WiFi networks after installing Asus ATK drivers

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, permissions, group-policy

I have installed ATKACPI driver and hotkey-related utilities. I cannot connect to WiFi networks after that (Windows doesn't show available networks), if I'm logged in as a non-administrative user. It works, if I'm logged in as Administrator.

OS: Windows 7 Pro

Comment: I assume I have to change one of the policies. However, I cannot find the one I need.